SQL Server DBT transformation incremental update not working if target table has an identity column
I am trying to update database using incremental approach using below,
{{ config(
    materialized='incremental',
    unique_key='mktdate',
    incremental_strategy='merge'
) }}

with source_data as 
(
    select
        current_mktdate,
        GETDATE() AS LastModifiedOn,
        *
    from dbo.pivot_market_data
)
select
    t.MarketDataID,
    s.*,
from 
    source_data s
left join 
    {{ this }} t on s.current_mktdate = t.mktdate

but marketdataid is an identity column in target database, so I'm getting this error:

Cannot update identity column 'MarketDataID'

If I remove t.MarketDataId from the select query, then I get this error:

Invalid column name 'MarketDataID'

How to resolve this issue?
I tried below configurations,
using merge_exclude_columns option,
{{ config(
    materialized='incremental',
    unique_key='mktdate',
    incremental_strategy='merge',
    merge_exclude_columns=['MarketDataID']
) }}

But I'm getting the same error:

Invalid column name 'MarketDataID'

I also tried this option:
{{ config(
    materialized='incremental',
    unique_key='mktdate',
    incremental_strategy='delete+insert',
    on_schema_change='sync_all_columns'
) }}

and got an error:

The object 'PK_MARKETDATA' is dependent on column 'MarketDataID'


I do not know DBT, but in a native SQL Server environment, you would need to use the IDENTITY_INSERT option. A web search for "dbt core identity_insert" yields several promising results including SO questions questions here and here.

One thing i never got is why SQL Server doesn't like to update IDENTITY columns

Many SQL Server access packages (ODBC,OleDb...) use Identity as  main row identification tool. That is, if someone changes identity, all current rowsets for all users (in frontend) become inconsistent. Therefore, this is an expensive and dangerous operation)
